# How to set XML node value as variable in SSIS

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, ssis, etl

I have a XML file requested from my web service. It contains a sessionID in the XML node.
XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<string>123-abs2g34-1231gsdfg-zcvbdf213-k2345hjksdfn31</string>
```

The string **123-abs2234-1231gsdfg-zcvbdf213-k2345hjksdfn31** is what I want to set as a variable. I have to pass this variable into next package in order to log in my account.

How can I do this?

I really appreciate for the help!

Comment: Are you expecting an output XML to be generated from the above input XML. If yes, please share the structure of the output XML.

Comment: No, I'm just expecting a string that contains sessionID so I am able to set it as a variable. Because in my next XML task, I have to use it as a input to request another web service method.

Comment: You can either transform the above XML using XSLT and output the value as `text` using `<xsl:value-of select="string">` or directly parse the XML containing the `<string>session ID</string>` into a `JSON`. This will convert the XML into a key value pair and read the value from the `JSON` and pass it to your next service.

Comment: My final goal is to automate this process, so I can not manually parse XML into JSON. And I tried to transform XML using XSLT, it will still give me another XML file, which I can't save it as variable(or I can't only save the text part). Is there any method to only save the string part into variable?

Comment: There are XML to JSON parsers which can be integrated in the code. You can look them up online. The most crude way to convert the XML as a string and in the code, write a condition to read the data between `>` and `</` using the string `substring` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Aniket V for helping me solved this problem. I created a XML task and use Aniket V's method by transforming XML to save the string into variable. Then I created an expression called "sessionID" using `SUBSTRING( @[User::Variable],39,36)` to extract the target string and pass it into next Web Service task.